# Why I can not publish clr function in visual studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Write simple clr function in c# and try to publish on `sql server 2016` but when right click on project and try to publish, I get this error:

> unable to connect to target server

Right click on the project and see target platform, select `sql server 2014`, I think my problem is that? open that drop down list and can not see `sql server 2014`.

How can I solve that publish error?

Comment: Try connecting to server in SSMS and import the dll file from there

Comment: @PawełKucharski please wait my friend to test that

Comment: @PawełKucharski i register that ddl file with this CREATE ASSEMBLY beh 
from 'D:\Database3.dll' ,now how can i call addTax function into that file?

Comment: you have to create a function first. Please refer to [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/791953/SQL-CLR-functions) article

Comment: @PawełKucharski can you post me script to create function to my assembly?i read that article and try to create function but not successfull!

Comment: I do not know the name of your assembly and function. You need to adjust the script accordingly.